# Show/Hide GridView Header in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a ListView in WPF, and I want to hide the headers for the ListView when the List the ItemsSource is bound to be null, and display the headers when the ItemsSource is not null and has at least 1 item in the collection. I have found the code online to hide the ListView headers like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HideListViewHeaders" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: How do I show the Headers after the list has data in it

Comment: your are forgetting to set target anem and target properties: